# Select without Group By Sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I got some problems with this query i need all my selectors but i only want to group `aspnet_Users.Userid` how should i do this?

Here is my query:

```
SELECT 
    aspnet_Users.UserId, aspnet_Users.UserName, 
    Friends.Verified, Friends.FriendUserId 
FROM 
    [aspnet_Users] 
INNER JOIN 
    Friends ON Friends.UserId = aspnet_Users.UserId OR Friends.FriendUserId = aspnet_Users.UserId
WHERE
    aspnet_Users.UserId IN 
       (SELECT UserId as Id FROM Friends 
        WHERE FriendUserId='3d1224ac-f2ad-45d4-aa84-a98e748e3e57'
        UNION 
        SELECT FriendUserId as Id FROM Friends 
        WHERE UserId='3d1224ac-f2ad-45d4-aa84-a98e748e3e57')
GROUP BY 
    aspnet_Users.UserId, aspnet_Users.UserName, 
    Friends.Verified, Friends.FriendUserId
```

**Stored Procedure structure:**

**Tables** [aspnet_Users] and [Friends]

**Columns** [aspnet_Users.UserId], [aspnet_Users.UserName], [Friends.Verified], [Friends.FriendUserId]

That is the data that i need to get using the procedure, but the problem is that each user can have multiply friends which means if so there will be multiply Friends values. This is the reason why i can't group using those values cause it gives me dublicates with the wrong value.

**Expected Output:**

**aspnet_Users.UserId** (This is the user id of the friend, note that it doesn't mean that its the FriendUserId)

**aspnet_Users.UserName** (This is the UserName of the friend based on the UserId explained above)

**Friends.Verified** (True or False. The Verified value in the Friends table on the friendship)

**Friends.FriendUserId** (The FriendUserId value from the table Friends)

Comment: I don't understand _why_ you want to group on only userid. Can you please show an example of your desired result?

Comment: I understand if you do group by aspnet_Users.UserId, it will be also by aspnet_Users.UserName. However you cannot group if no aggregate function is present. I think you want to use order by. However expected output as example will help.

Comment: This doesn't make sense, what do you want the output data to look like?

Comment: @Parek But if a user can have multiple friends, and you want the friends in your output, then how do you want to show those rows if a user must be unique? Some examples are: 1. Show a count of nbr of friends. 2. Comma-separated list of friends.

Comment: Edited again, now with expected output. It was hard to explain :/

Comment: @Parek I understand that you want to show the two columns from the friend-table, but how do you want to format it considering your requirement that each user-row should be unique?

Comment: Can we take this in a chat please? ;>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your relationship is not fully reciprocal in the table Friends, you can use this query.

Otherwise either part of the UNION would work on its own

```
SELECT U.UserId, U.UserName, F.Verified, F.FriendUserId
FROM Friends F
JOIN aspnet_Users U ON U.UserId=F.UserId
WHERE F.FriendUserId='3d1224ac-f2ad-45d4-aa84-a98e748e3e57'
UNION 
SELECT U.UserId, U.UserName, F.Verified, F.FriendUserId
FROM Friends F
JOIN aspnet_Users U ON U.UserId=F.FriendUserId
WHERE F.UserId='3d1224ac-f2ad-45d4-aa84-a98e748e3e57'
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to group? You aren't using any aggregate functions (eg sum, count)

You haven't made it clear what results you're looking for - I'm guessing all details of users connected with a given user, including the user themselves?

Surely you can just do something like:

```
Select a.userid, a.username, f.verified, f.userid  
From aspnet_users a  
  Full outer join friends f on f.frienduserid = a.userid  
Where a.userid = @userid or f.frienduserid = @userid
```

Comment: The problem is that i get duplicates then.. :/

Comment: So can you give some examples of input data and what you want returned?

Comment: What I mean is, say Joe is the user that has that userid. If he's friends with Bill and Sally, should there be two records returned?  In your database, are you storing reciprocal relationships ie there would be Joe-Bill, Joe-Sally, Bill-Joe and Sally-Joe records in your friends table?

Comment: Exactly, just like you imagined

Comment: Which bit?  1. Two records. 2. Four records. Once that part is answered, how many records do you want to see in the output?

Answer (score -1):

You can use DISTINCT

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    aspnet_Users.UserId, aspnet_Users.UserName, 
    Friends.Verified, Friends.FriendUserId 
FROM 
    [aspnet_Users] 
INNER JOIN 
    Friends ON Friends.UserId = aspnet_Users.UserId OR Friends.FriendUserId = aspnet_Users.UserId
WHERE
    aspnet_Users.UserId IN 
       (SELECT UserId as Id FROM Friends 
        WHERE FriendUserId='3d1224ac-f2ad-45d4-aa84-a98e748e3e57'
        UNION 
        SELECT FriendUserId as Id FROM Friends 
        WHERE UserId='3d1224ac-f2ad-45d4-aa84-a98e748e3e57')
```

Comment: This is the same as grouping on all columns.

Comment: Just as Andreas said this is like grouping on all of the columns so this didn't solve my problem.